# Ember 2.11.0-beta.2: How do include templates from pods with partial

Tags: ember.js

**Solution Credits Falke:**
**Correct Version**

```
modulePrefix: 'yourAppName',
podModulePrefix: 'yourAppName/pods',
```

**Wrong: Not Good**

```
modulePrefix: 'yourAppName',
podModulePrefix: 'pods',
```

**Note**: Also with the wrong version partial templates works until you try to reference partial from templates in pods!

**OLD QUESTION**
**My Pod structure is:**
pods/navbar/template.hbs and try to include this template in the application.hbs.

I am not be able to include the template as partial, couse i recieve an error in the console.

***Uncaught Error: Compile Error: * is not a partial***

What i have to do, to include partical templates in other templates? What's the right spelling?

[image: pods/navbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application.hbs file call the template partial helper and supply the name of the template/partial you want to render as the argument.

```
{{partial "navbar"}}
```

by default the ember resolver first look for Pods before the traditional project structure.
https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#using-pods

You should also set the `podModulePrefix` in your `config/enviroment.js` file.

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
var ENV = {
  modulePrefix: 'app',
  podModulePrefix: 'app/pods',
  ..........
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. I know this way, but the problem the console shows only ember.debug.js:51528 Uncaught Error: Compile Error: navbar is not a partial(…). My pod navbar template lies under app/pods/navbar/template.hbs i use Ember 2.11.0-beta.2

Comment: I improved the answer,

Comment: The  podModulePrefix: 'masonry/pods', does the job, i had only  podModulePrefix: 'pods', without the modulePrefix name. Thank you very much.